# Unable to Destroy Activity while Buffering Video on Pressing Back

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, onbackpressed

I have written a Video Player that streams from a Host Server. Sometimes the Buffering  takes a long time. When the User Presses Back the onDestroy() of the Activity is not being called {and after sometime an ANR is thrown. It's as if the System is trying to destroy the Actvity on the UI thread, hence the ANR.}

I am not concerned about the ANR, I want to know why the onDestroy method is not called while Buffering is in Progress.

Thanks and Regards,
Shashi Kiran G M

Comment: onDestroy() is never guaranteed to get called. Use onPause() for what you want to do. onPause() is a misleading name. It actually means the activity's UI thread is onPause, not the application itself. For coming back, use onResume(), again misleading name it's the activity's UI thread that's coming back.

Comment: What stephan says. onDestroy() is probably used for garbage collection, java has something similar on objects.

Comment: @gmsk19 Am also facing the same issue, are you able to fix it. Am thinking to integrate vitamio player but the sdk size is almost 4mb :(

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know why the onDestroy method is not called while Buffering
>   is in Progress.

To be honest, i dont know why. All i know is, the one that will be called everytime is `onPause`. `onDestroy` sometimes get called, sometimes not. Hence, there is nothing wrong with your apps.

That is the reason i put my code in `onPause` in most situation (except if i want to do something **only** if the activity is destroyed, not paused)